# Trouble deleting spaces from string in df and joining datetime (Y-M-D) and (H:M:S) columns

Tags: python, pandas, string, datetime

I am learning pandas and I am struggling to convert a column of strings (HH:MM:SS) to datetimes and join it with another column of datetimes (%Y-%M-%D).

I kept getting an "out of bounds" error when trying to convert the strings. Eventually, I came to suspect that the strings might contain spaces that were, for some reason, being interpreted as the year zero, which is before the earliest allowable date. So, I converted the column to a list to see the string in quotations, and sure enough, there are spaces on each end of the string.

Now I'm struggling to remove the spaces efficiently, and have had to take a circuitous approach to getting rid of them. I'd be grateful for an explanation of why **df.replace** didn't work, below, and whether there's a more efficient way to do it than I have come up with.

Here's the relevant code and its results (taken from nested 'sheet' / 'column' for loops that I have left out):

IN:

```
print(f"{relevant_sheets[sheet][column].head()} is type {pd.api.types.infer_dtype(relevant_sheets[sheet][column])}\n")
```

OUT:

```
0     03:18:38 
1     03:42:45 
2     04:02:52 
3     04:32:02 
4     04:32:03 
Name:   CALL TIME  , dtype: object is type string
```

I converted the series to a list to see whether there are unseen spaces in there:

IN:

```
times = relevant_sheets[sheet][column].head().tolist()
print(f"{times}\n")
```

OUT:

```
[' 03:18:38 ', ' 03:42:45 ', ' 04:02:52 ', ' 04:32:02 ', ' 04:32:03 ']
```

Sure enough, there they are.

So I tried to apply a .replace to the series:

IN:

```
relevant_sheets[sheet][column] = relevant_sheets[sheet][column].replace(" ", "")
times = relevant_sheets[sheet][column].head().tolist()
print(f"{times}\n")
```

OUT:

```
[' 03:18:38 ', ' 03:42:45 ', ' 04:02:52 ', ' 04:32:02 ', ' 04:32:03 ']
```

It didn't work. The spaces are still there.

So I tried applying the same .replace method to the list I had extracted. (There was a NaN that was being treated as a float, so I had to convert everything to strings, even though all but the single NaN already were strings.)

IN:

```
times = [str(time).replace(" ", "") for time in times]
print(f"{times}\n")
```

OUT:

```
['03:18:38', '03:42:45', '04:02:52', '04:32:02', '04:32:03']
```

Success. The spaces are gone.

**But why??** Why did **.replace** work on the individual strings, but not when applied to the series?

Anyway, I ran a test to see whether this solved the "out of bounds" error, I was getting, and it did:

IN:

```
relevant_sheets[sheet][column] = pd.to_datetime(times)
print(f"{relevant_sheets[sheet][column]}\n")
print(f"{relevant_sheets[sheet][column]} is type{pd.api.types.infer_dtype(relevant_sheets[sheet][column])}\n")
```

OUT:

```
      CALL TIME  
0   2022-05-21 03:18:38
1   2022-05-21 03:42:45
2   2022-05-21 04:02:52
3   2022-05-21 04:32:02
4   2022-05-21 04:32:03
..                  ...
```

Now I need to figure out how to get rid of the 2022-05-21 and how to merge this Time column with a %Y-%M-%D Date column.

time_column is the CALL TIME column above.

date_column looks like this:

```
                                               CALL DATE  
0                                  2017-07-12 00:00:00
1                                  2017-07-12 00:00:00
2                                  2017-07-12 00:00:00
3                                  2017-07-12 00:00:00
4                                  2017-07-12 00:00:00
```

This is what I've tried:

```
relevant_sheets[sheet]['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(relevant_sheets[sheet][date_column].astype(str) + ' ' +relevant_sheets[sheet][time_column].astype(str))
```

But I get this:

```
ValueError: to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be specified: [day,month,year] is missing
```

Can someone please explain why this is so complicated and suggest a simpler and more effective approach?

Comment: [`pd.Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) replaces complete elements while in order to replace substrings you need [`pd.Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html). `str(time).replace` is not related to pandas at all, it's the built-in string replace method.

Comment: By the way, you might want to take a look at [`pd.Series.str.strip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html), another string function whose purpose is to remove leading and trailing whitespace (or other characters) from strings.

Comment: For the second part of your question, that whoever closed the question did not see...first join the columns `date` and `time`, and then apply the `to_datetime`.  `pd.to_datetime((df['CALL DATE']+' '+df['CALL TME']).str.replace("\s+"," ").str.strip())`